# Stop audio playback

Tags: android, audio, back

I am new to Android programming and i have a problem that i can not solve without your help...Please, give me a hand... ;-)

**When i start playing my audio file, i can not stop it. Instead, I am quitting the application.**

*I play audio file with this code:*

public class Word1Audio extends Activity {

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word1video);



        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lige);
      mediaPlayer.start();



    }

}
```

*HOWEVER, when i try to stop it when the **back button** is pressed by this piece of code*

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// do something on back.
return;
}
```

my applications closes down and audio continues to play...

**Do you have an idea why the application closes down? And how can i just stop the music and go back to the previous page...??**

Thank you for your time and help... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word1video);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lige);
    mediaPlayer.start();
 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if( mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ) {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :-) The script works partially... It works well when i try to play the audio once. When i try to play it the second time it starts playing 2 same audios simultaneously:  one audio from the beginning and the other from the place it was stopped previously.

Comment: Do you have an idea why it does that?

Comment: Look at the state diagram. Once the player is stopped, you must call prepare() before playing again. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html